# How to set time with timezone?

Tags: php

In my project time shows as

```
"2017-01-01 12:00:00+03:00".
```

How to make it as

```
"2017-01-01 15:00:00"
```

?

Comment: and what you had tried?

Comment: @AshishPatel wrong!

Comment: So yo basically want to convert it from TZ +3 to TZ + 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time `2017-01-01 12:00:00+03:00` means that it is hour `12:00:00` in the timezone of `+3` hours. You don't want to do anything just to reformat your time to different display:

```
(new DateTime($yourDateInStringOrUnix))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and you will get

```
`2017-01-01 12:00:00` //This is local time in timezone of +3 hour
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s A",strtotime('2017-01-01 12:00:00+03:00'));
```

But you will get `09:00:00 AM` not `15:00:00 AM` because your time is `+3` ahead

https://eval.in/822865

Answer (score 0):

You want to add offset to your current time. Separate datetime with offset and recalculate it.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$date = '2017-01-01 12:00:00+03:00';

$datetime = substr($date, 0, 19); // Get date time string
$offset = substr($date, 19);  // Extract Offset

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $offset);
$seconds = $hours * 60 * 60 + $minutes * 60; // Convert offset to seconds

// Recalculate date time by adding offset
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime) + $seconds);

?>
```

> Output
>
> 2017-01-01 15:00:00

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can make it like this.

If this is coming from your data you can do it like this:

```
$my_date = "2017-01-01 12:00:00+03:00";
$converted_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($my_date));
echo $converted_date;
```

But if you are getting the current date and time only you can make it this way;

```
$my_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $my_date;
```

Comment: Why I got buttoms down? my answer is correct though.